# How does Magento_payment/transparent work?

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

I'm trying to get a payment gateway up and running, and it appears that the majority of the built-in payment gateways use the following code for their credit card form:

```
<iframe width="0"
    height="0"
    data-bind="src: getSource(), attr: {id: getCode() + '-transparent-iframe', 'data-container': getCode() + '-transparent-iframe'}"
    allowtransparency="true"
    frameborder="0"
    name="iframeTransparent"
    class="payment-method-iframe">
</iframe>
<form class="form" id="co-transparent-form" method="post"  data-bind="mageInit: {
    'transparent':{
        'context': context(),
        'controller': getControllerName(),
        'gateway': getCode(),
        'orderSaveUrl':getPlaceOrderUrl(),
        'cgiUrl': getCgiUrl(),
        'dateDelim': getDateDelim(),
        'cardFieldsMap': getCardFieldsMap(),
        'nativeAction': getSaveOrderUrl()
    }, 'validation':[]}">

    <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form' --><!-- /ko -->
</form>
```

However, when I press the Submit button, no credit card data is being passed to the server (I know this because when I look at Chrome's dev tools, none of the requests contain CC info, encrypted or otherwise).  This is true for my custom payment gateway, but I've tested it on Magento's Authorize.NET plugin, and it doesn't pass any credit card information, but still somehow manages to work.

How do I get the credit card info so I can pass it to my payment gateway?